# How do I pass data to an op in a different module in dagster?

Tags: python, orchestration, dagster

I am new to dagster and am having a difficult time sorting this one out.  I have to jobs defined in my dagster pipeline and I want to pass data from an op in one job to an op in another

My setup is as such (simplified example)

job1.py

```py
@op()
def generate_num():
    return 3
@op()
def increase_num(generate_num):
    return generate_num + 1
@job()
def increment_up():
    increase_num(generate_num))
```

job2.py

```
@op()
def decrease_num(generate_num)
    generate_num - 1
@op()
def multiple_num(decrease_num)
    decrease_num * 2
@job()
def get_multiple():
    multiple_num(decrease_num())
```

where the value returned from "generate_num" is passed to job2.py.  Is this totally off base to try?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't just reuse `generate_num` in the second job? like

```py
from job1 import generate_num

@op()
def decrease_num(generate_num)
    generate_num - 1
@op()
def multiple_num(decrease_num)
    decrease_num * 2
@job()
def get_multiple():
    multiple_num(decrease_num(generate_num()))
```

Comment: that is my question.  How can I make sure the job2.py knows that "generate_num" exists on job1.py?

Comment: it doesn't have to know where else "generate_num" is used. you can simply reuse ops as many times as you want in any jobs or graphs. it just needs to be imported into or defined in the job2.py

Comment: thanks this is very helpful.  I think I see my problem here.  Doing as the above requires that I rerun generate_num when I execute job 2.  What I'd really like to do is store the output of generate_num when I run job 1 and then reference that later when I run job 2. Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to think about this in Dagster is with assets. I.e. the value produced by `generate_num` in the first job and used in the second job
will live somewhere in persistent storage outside the scope of any job run. An asset is an object in persistent storage, like a file or a table.

Here's an example with two jobs that share an asset:

```py
from dagster import Definitions, AssetSelection, asset, define_asset_job


@asset
def num():
    return 3


@asset
def num_plus_one(num):
    return num + 1


@asset
def num_multiplied(num):
    return num + 2


defs = Definitions(
    assets=[num, num_plus_one, num_multiplied],
    jobs=[
        define_asset_job("inc_job", AssetSelection.assets(num, num_plus_one)),
        define_asset_job("multi_job", AssetSelection.assets(num_multiplied)),
    ],
)
```

When you run the first job, a file will be created for both `num` and `num_plus_one`. When you run the second job, it will use the contents of the `num` file to compute `num_multiplied`.